# WSL in vscode with jutyer notebook error 'no module named showast'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, wsl-2

When I first ran the code in the Jupyter notebook, there was a syntax that could not be executed in Python 3.8 version.
So, I downloaded version 3.9 from the terminal, set the 3.9 kernel in vscode, and ran it again, but an error occurred saying that 'no module named showast'

I check python version at terminal
$ python -V
Python 3.9.18
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.10

Is that something wrong with pip install directory?

Comment: did you re-install that plugin after switching python versions?

Comment: you mean 'pip uninstall showast'? I try it but doesn't work.

Comment: After you switched to 3.9 did you do `python -m pip install showast`?